# What does the "3" in $d^3x_1d^3p_1\ldots d^3x_Nd^3p_N$ mean here?

Tags: notation, physics, statistical-mechanics

On page 4 of [this](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/noahmiller/files/statistical_mechanics.pdf) online lecture notes, I find the following notation:
$$d^3x_1d^3p_1\ldots d^3x_Nd^3p_N$$

What does the raised "3" next to the "d" mean?

Comment: Raised to the power of $3$. Cubed. I think.

Comment: @Ajay It's alluding to a third power, but seeing as these are likely to be differentials, not regular variables, the truth is likely a bit more subtle. (It's on page 4 of the pdf, by the way. For anyone who doesn't want to search through it all.)

Comment: Interesting...thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation may be found on page 2 of the document. Here is an image:

[image]

It's the same number as the 6N here:

[image]

You have $N$ particles with 3 position and 3 momentum values each.

Comment: Suzu, +1 for quoting the notes.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an index indicating that you are considering a volume (3D) integral. Each of the $x_j$ and $p_j$ is a vector with $3$ components.